# Error 403 when accessing a page in Asp .Net

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a website. On my test and staging environment I can access a page. I disabled session state for that page and I store the session ID in the url for the entire application.

But when I test on live, I get a 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied page.

I use ASP .Net Webforms 4.0 and IIS 7.5.

I believe it's related to the configuration because on staging I have exactly the same environment as in live and both staging and live run on the same machine.

I don't use url rewrite or anything similar. Also the pages use SSL but the staging environment uses SSL too and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the account that your application pool is running under has permissions to access the directory containing your deployed website.

Comment: I can access the entire website and other pages that reside in the same directory as the page that I can't access so this shouldn't be a problem